# VBS function always returns False when a certain variable is defined

Tags: variables, vbscript

When running the below VBS function to check if the current user is in a certain Security Group, I get error #500 (Variable is undefined) for the line `strGroup = LCase(Join(CurrentUser.MemberOf))`.

I have `Option Explicit` declared in the script, so that is not surprising. However, when I do declare the variable (`Dim strGroup`), the function stops working and always returns false.

```
Function is_group_member(group)

    Dim objNetwork
    Dim objUser
    Dim CurrentUser

    ' Set our default return value
    is_group_member = False 

    ' Directory Lookup
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Set objUser = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
    Set CurrentUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objUser.UserName)

    strGroup = LCase(Join(CurrentUser.MemberOf))    

    ' Set return value to true if the user is in the selected group 
    If InStr(strGroup, lcase(group)) Then
        is_group_member = True  
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess `CurrentUser.MemberOf` isn't what you think it is.

You need to debug your running script (or if that's not possible, get some logging in there that writes values to the console or to a log file).

You need check

1. that `CurrentUser` is not nothing
2. that `CurrentUser.MemberOf` is not nothing
3. that `CurrentUser.MemberOf` is an array
4. that `CurrentUser.MemberOf` is an array of strings
5. that `CurrentUser.MemberOf` contains the group that you are
   expecting.

Use the [TypeName](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_typename.asp) function to determine the type of a variable / member

The VBScript debugger can be found here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22185 to Debug the script, install the debugger, then either start the script by passing //x to cscript (`cscript //x MyScript.vbs`) or put the `stop` keyword in your script where you want to start debugging

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll have a look at that. It looks like your link to the debugger is incorrect though, as the page cannot be found. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the download link, I've fixed it up.

Comment: Thanks. Off to a couple of meetings, will grab it later today.